# Having an exact difference value between two Date value

Tags: java

I want to do somthing like this:

```
    Date startDate = new Date();
 // Do Something
    Date endDate = new Date();
    double msElapsedTime =endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime();
```

I have the result value in milisecond like this:`7.0` but I want to have the exaxt value for example:`7.15`

How can I do that?

Comment: @NaveenKumar what to show ??They both are date objects.

Comment: No,`getTime()` returns long.

Comment: use System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀyes but the result is i.e 7

Comment: @TangoStar remember you are subtracting two `long` values.Edit your post and tell us what you are exactly trying to do,So you may get correct option.

Comment: You are typecasting long - long => double. `7.15` can never be result with long operands.

Comment: @javaBeginner The use of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is discouraged one should use `System.nanoTime()` as @Joop Eggen suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**System.nanoTime()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime()
// Do Something
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
// to get microsecond value
double msElapsedTime = ((double) (endTime - startTime)) / 1000.0;
```